# What does "suggests after the event..." mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Just as the development of a society sometimes **suggests after the event** a pattern not in the minds of its creators, the transition from the old convict system to the new did not always follow the recommendations of Bigge.

(emphasis added)

I don't understand "suggests after the event..."

Comment: Welcome! Can you try to clarify specifically what it is that you don't understand in that sentence?

Comment: You should [edit] to add the source for this quote. What book is it from?

Comment: It's from the book "A short history of Australia" by Manning Clark.

Comment: It’s a strange sentence.  The word “event” refers to the “development of a society”.   We usually use the word “event” to mean something that happens in {a relatively short amount of time},  not something that {happens over many decades or several hundred years.}

Answer (score 1):

"Suggests after the event" means "we're looking back at the situation."

It's different from trying to see what's going on during the events.

It's also "suggests," which indicates that when looking back they aren't certain of everything.

> the development of a society sometimes suggests after the event a pattern not in the minds of its creators

We can take that and turn it into this:

> When we look back in history, we often see what looks like society developing in ways not predicted by the people who tried to change it.

Now this doesn't slot back into the original sentence as well, but it should get the point across.

Comment: Can I understand "suggests after the event" as "indicates that behind the occurence"?

Comment: No, that would be about causes.

Comment: I appreciate your help but I still didn't understand it clearly. :x

Is "event" related to "development of a society"?

Comment: Yes, it is. "Event" in this case is referring to something like a historical events, so revolutions or important inventions or something similar to that, that affects the entire society.

Answer (score 0):

There are two key parts to the phrase: "suggests" and "after the event".

To "suggest", as used here, is to say that this is a possibility but not a certainty, or that the evidence points in this direction but is not conclusive. Like if I said, "The discovery of a large amount of cash hidden in Mr Smith's house suggests that he may be involved in criminal activity." It is not proof. There may be other explanations. But it is a possibility.

"After the event" means that the people under discussion did not see this at the time the event happened. They didn't see it until later, until "after" the event.

So to say that something "suggests after the event" is to say that after something happened, looking back you see that there are clues to some mystery or discovery. In this case, it appears that the writer is saying that people sometimes push for a social change, and that after the change happens, a "pattern" can be seen that is not what the people who started the social change intended or expected.